# Adding attribute to thinking sphinx index config causing indexing fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

Given schema:

```
create_table "letters", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "title",      limit: 255
t.text     "content",    limit: 16777215
t.date     "issue_date"
t.datetime "created_at",                  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                  null: false
t.integer  "osha_id",    limit: 4
t.string   "status",     limit: 255
end
```

indices/letter_index.rb

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :letter, :with => :real_time do
# fields
indexes title, :sortable => true
indexes content
indexes issue_date_as_string

# attributes
has status, :type => :string
has created_at, :type => :timestamp
has updated_at, :type => :timestamp
end
```

When I `rake ts:regenerate` without the `has status, :type => :string` line, it generates the index just fine.

But when I add that line in, I get a screenful of error messages, of which the most relevant seems to be

```
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in '<top (required)>' 
Mysql2::Error: unknown column: 'status'
```

I'm absolutely befuddled at what the error is trying to tell me and why it's failing in the first place.  Am I missing something obvious?

[edited to add more information]

complete error output (after it dumps the contents of the database):

```
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/connection.rb:93:in `rescue in query'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/connection.rb:96:in `query'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/connection.rb:73:in `execute'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/real_time/transcriber.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in copy'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/connection.rb:39:in `block in take'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/innertube-1.1.0/lib/innertube.rb:138:in `take'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/connection.rb:37:in `take'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/real_time/transcriber.rb:20:in `block in copy'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/logger.rb:3:in `log'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/real_time/transcriber.rb:19:in `copy'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/real_time/populator.rb:16:in `block in populate'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:124:in `find_in_batches'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/querying.rb:9:in `find_in_batches'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/real_time/populator.rb:15:in `populate'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/real_time/populator.rb:3:in `populate'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/rake_interface.rb:30:in `block in generate'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/rake_interface.rb:29:in `each'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/rake_interface.rb:29:in `generate'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/tasks.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Mysql2::Error: unknown column: 'status'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:80:in `_query'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:80:in `block in query'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:79:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:79:in `query'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/connection.rb:121:in `results_for'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/connection.rb:88:in `query'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/connection.rb:73:in `execute'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/real_time/transcriber.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in copy'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/connection.rb:39:in `block in take'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/innertube-1.1.0/lib/innertube.rb:138:in `take'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/connection.rb:37:in `take'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/real_time/transcriber.rb:20:in `block in copy'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/logger.rb:3:in `log'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/real_time/transcriber.rb:19:in `copy'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/real_time/populator.rb:16:in `block in populate'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:124:in `find_in_batches'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/querying.rb:9:in `find_in_batches'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/real_time/populator.rb:15:in `populate'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/real_time/populator.rb:3:in `populate'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/rake_interface.rb:30:in `block in generate'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/rake_interface.rb:29:in `each'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/rake_interface.rb:29:in `generate'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.2.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/tasks.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => ts:regenerate => ts:generate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

further gratuitous information-- This shows the various things I've tried, all of which have failed with the same `unknown column` error:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :letter, :with => :real_time do
  # fields
  indexes title, :sortable => true
  indexes content
  #indexes issue_date
  indexes issue_date_as_string # this one works!
  #indexes status
  #indexes status_as_string
  #indexes osha_id
  #indexes issue_date

  # attributes
  #has status, :type => :string
  has created_at, :type => :timestamp
  has updated_at, :type => :timestamp
end
```

The `*_as_string` methods are just a shot in the dark:

models/letter.rb:

```
# experimental for thinking sphinx indexing on issue date
def issue_date_as_string
  self.issue_date.to_s
end

def status_as_string
  self.status.to_s
end
```

Comment: Tim, I can't spot anything obviously wrong. Are you able to share the full error output?

Comment: updated. thanks for looking.

Comment: FWIW, I didn't see anything about attribute accessors being needed, but I added `attr_accessor :status` to the model with no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appreciate all the extra detail Tim.

I think the issue here is related to a bug in Thinking Sphinx which leads to index files not being properly cleared out by `ts:regenerate` and thus they're still using the old schema (without the `status` attribute). This means any attempts to populate new data is going to hit that error.

However, I've fixed this bug a little while ago, and the v3.3.0 release of Thinking Sphinx includes it. Can you upgrade (there are [no breaking changes](https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/releases/tag/v3.3.0)) and see if that fixes the problem?

Comment: So far, so good :)  Thought I was losing my mind.  This might fix the problem I was having with sphinx_scope also, I hope.

Comment: This also fixed the problems I was having with scopes.  Thank you!